# JSONObject cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion

Tags: java, json, websocket, type-conversion, invocation

(newb alert)

I'm using [Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) and [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/).

After resolving problems with `put`ting to a `JSONObject` with this question [How to avoid Eclipse warnings when using legacy code without generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646613/how-to-avoid-eclipse-warnings-when-using-legacy-code-without-generics/2646843#2646843), I'm now trying to [`sendToAll`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/example/ChatServer.java) [`obj`](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_1-1_-_Encode_a_JSON_object) but am getting

```
error: method sendToAll in class WebSocketServerBase cannot be applied 
 to given types;
                ws.sendToAll(obj);
                  ^
  required: String
  found: JSONObject
  reason: actual argument JSONObject cannot be converted to String by method 
   invocation conversion
1 error
```

How can I `sendToAll` `obj`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj` is a `JSONObject`, and the method requires a `String`. I'm sure there is some way to convert your `obj` into a `String` identifying it, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Please do a bit more research and find the answer, then I'll upvote for a fast response.

Comment: very surpirisng, as I know nothing whatsoever about json!! I know how to read compiler errors